# Extended Hanoi Tower

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

**Problem Definition**

I'm trying write a c++ program to solve the `Extended Hanoi Tower` problem.

Extended Hanoi Tower is similar to the standard hanoi problem. The difference is that, odd rings are in **A** (1, 3, 5, ...) and even rings are in **B** (2, 4, 6, ...). The question asks, how can we transfer all of the rings to **C** in a **recursive** way?
I've written what I've done so far.
Any help letting me implement my approach or Any ideas to implement the program would be appreciated !
Thanks !

**Rules**

1. Only one disk can be moved at a time.
2. No disk may be placed on top of a smaller disk.
3. The output should contain the necessary moves, not the *minimum* necessary moves
4. The total number of disks may be **even or odd**.
5. Implementation should be recursive.

**Approach 1**

we assume that the problem has been solved for n-1 rings that are currently in A and B. That means they are all moved to C and C have 2n-2 ordered rings. After that we have to handle the remaining rings in A & B. That means we have to take smaller ring and place it on the bigger ring (from B to A). After that we have to  merge the rings in C (2n-2) and the rings in A (2). Finally we have to use standard Hanoi solution to reach our goal and move all of the rings to C.

**Implementation 1**

```
int main()
{
    long int n;
    cin >> n;
    // move odd & even rings to the first shaft, recursively
    customHanoi(n);
    // move all rings from first shaft to the destination shaft, recursively
    standardHanoi(n);
    return 0;
}

// the shaft holds the odd rings: A
// the shaft holds the even rings: B
// the final destination shaft: C
void customHanoi(int n, char A, char B, char C)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return;
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        cout << B << " " << A << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (n == 3)
    {
        cout << A << " " << C << endl;
        cout << B << " " << A << endl;
        cout << C << " " << A << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // here we have some missing code !
    }
}

// a recursive function to find the solution for standard hanoi
void standardHanoi(int n, char from, char helper, char to)
{
    // the base condition
    if (n == 1)
    {
        cout << from << " " << to << endl;
        return;
    }
    // the recursive calls
    standardHanoi(n - 1, from, to, helper);
    cout << from << " " << to << endl;
    standardHanoi(n - 1, helper, from, to);
}
```

**Releated Resources**

[Link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/an-alternative-hanoi-tower-problem)

Comment: `n` should refer to number of disks in total. so, there's no `2n-2`.

Comment: my explanation was based on this assumption that `n` is the number of disks in each rod. but my source code used `n` for the total number of disks in A & B. Thanks for your attention & Also for your quick response !

Comment: you can't make that assumption. there can be *odd* number of disks in total.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about myself. Your emphasis guided me to the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @Will-Ness !! 
This is one of the possible solutions. 
Hope this helps ! :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function declarations
void customHanoi(long int, char = 'A', char = 'B', char = 'C');
void standardHanoi(long int, char = 'A', char = 'B', char = 'C');

int main()
{
    // initialize the variable
    long int n;
    // getting the number of rings
    cin >> n;
    // move odd & even rings to the first shaft, recursively
    // after that move all rings from first shaft to the destination shaft
    customHanoi(n);
    // our program finished successfully
    return 0;
}

// A: the shaft that holds odd rings
// B: the shaft that holds even rigns
// C: the final destination shaft
void customHanoi(long int n, char A, char B, char C)
{
    // initialize the variable
    static long int level = 1;

    // we can't handle zero/negative disk
    if (n < 1)
        return;

    // the base condition of recursion
    if (level == n)
    {
        // now, we moved all rings to the first shaft
        // so, we have to move them to the destination shaft
        standardHanoi(n);
        // finish the execution of recursion
        return;
    }

    // reordering the disks
    // based on even or odd number of disks & current level
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    {
        if (level % 2 == 1)
            standardHanoi(level, A, C, B);
        else
            standardHanoi(level, B, C, A);
    }
    else
    {
        if (level % 2 == 1)
            standardHanoi(level, B, C, A);
        else
            standardHanoi(level, A, C, B);
    }

    // go to the next level, it helps us control the flow
    level++;
    // the recursive calls
    customHanoi(n);
}

// a recursive function to find the solution for standard hanoi
void standardHanoi(long int n, char from, char helper, char to)
{
    // the base condition
    if (n == 1)
    {
        cout << from << " " << to << endl;
        return;
    }
    // the recursive calls
    standardHanoi(n - 1, from, to, helper);
    cout << from << " " << to << endl;
    standardHanoi(n - 1, helper, from, to);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can put 1 from A over 2 on B.

We can put 1,2 from B over 3 on A by Standard Hanoi. All the other disks are larger and can be ignored.

We can put 1,2,3 from A over 4 on B by Standard Hanoi. All the other disks are larger and can be ignored.    ........

When we've arranged all disks on one pole, they are either on A (if total number of disks was odd) or B (even).

Move them all to C by Standard Hanoi.

Although, this may be considered an iterative approach, while you asked for a recursive one.

So, recursive: assume there's `n` disks in total. Move `n-1` disks to C by recursive application. Move `n-1` disks from C to A (`n` is odd) or B (`n` is even) by Standard Hanoi. Move the resulting `n` disks to C by Standard Hanoi.

This is very similar to what you proposed, except `n` stands for the total number of disks (rings). It is also not purely recursive.